# Default button in Window created with CreateWindowEx()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I've created a window using `CreateWindowEx` which functions as a wizard dialog using the following code;

```
DWORD dwStyle = WS_DLGFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, _T("WIZARD"), _T("SETUP"), dwStyle, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, WIZARD_WIDTH, WIZARD_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, g_hInstance, this);
```

In the `WM_CREATE` handler I create the bottom 'Next', 'Back' and 'Cancel' buttons, on the Next' button I set the style `BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON` and I send the `DM_SETDEFID` to the window with the ID of the next button. The button displays like a next button but hitting return on any of the input fields does nothing (None have `ES_WANTRETURN` set).

What am I doing wrong? I can post more code if I've missed anything vital out.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Are you calling [IsDialogMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your message loop?

Comment: Yes, I do call IsDialogMessage() in my loop, if it returns false then I call TranslateMessage() and DispatchMessage().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DM_SETDEFID` message is normally processed by `DefDlgProc`. If you're calling `DefWindowProc` instead, then you need to handle that message yourself so that when `IsDialogMessage` sends your window a `DM_GETDEFID` message, you'll know how to respond.